# Azure Databricks creating unnecessary folders

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

Azure Databricks creating random folders while writing and merging.

I run the below query in databricks:

```
df.write.format('delta').mode('overwrite').save("abfss://container@storage.dfs.core.windows.net/some_path/events")
```

When I am checking the azure storage UI, I am seeing some folders:
[image: enter image d escription here]

What are these folder **xJ**? And why it is getting created?

The description of the query:

engineInfo: Databricks-Runtime/13.2.x-scala2.12
isolationLevel: WriteSerializable

[image]

Comment: All I think of, is that it's an option of `tar` command. `tar -xJ`. I have no clue why you get this.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by using global spark session of databricks instead of creating a local spark session. I am still unsure why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The specific folder name '**xJ'** is likely a
  randomly generated identifier that Delta Lake uses internally. It's part of the structure that Delta Lake employs to manage data
  efficiently and reliably.
- These internal folders are not meant to be directly accessed or
  modified by users. They are essential for Delta Lake's functioning and are managed automatically by the Delta Lake system.

I have tried both Local and Global spark sessions and perfromed the write and Merge operations to ADLS:

**Below is the Global spark session:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
data = [('Alice', 34), ('Bob', 55), ('Charlie', 45)]
columns = ['name', 'age']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
df.write.format('delta').mode('overwrite').save("abfss://folder02@dileepstoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/1_path/events")
new_data = [('Dave', 28), ('Eva', 38)]
new_df = spark.createDataFrame(new_data, columns)
new_df.write.format('delta').mode('append').save("abfss://folder02@dileepstoragegen2.dfs.core.windows.net/1_path/events")
```

[image]

By following this Global spark session approach, you can ensure that the operations are consistent and that you avoid any unexpected folder creation or naming issues during the write and merge operations in Azure Databricks using Delta Lake.

Comment: Is there any specific reason, why those folders are getting created when we use local sessions?

Comment: It is an databricks internal procedure for managing delta lake system.